# Sql server and laravel 5

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, laravel-5

I think I created conection but when I try simple query it return this:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Table_1'. (SQL: select * from [Table_1])
```

Here is my config:

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'WIN-THR4E35I6N6\SQLEXPRESS'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test123'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'test123'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'test321'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
        ],
```

Anyone know what can be problem?

Comment: Does your database have a table named Table_1?

Comment: Hi, Vladimir, I am also facing the same issue, did you find any solution for same?